# adjust pan is not working for parameters that are out side of scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, scrollview

Im using adjust pan in my manifest activity and its working properly for scroll view but i have something out of scroll view that is resizing .

i put this code on activity on manifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

you can see that in the picture .

[image: Left one is before showing keyboard and right one is after showing keyboard]

im using it beside viewpager :

this is my viewpager xml that contain a lot of edittext .

**Fragment Xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerKind"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerSazande"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/model"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="مدل"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/serial"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="سریال"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LIMEI"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/IMEI1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="IMEI"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/IMEI2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="IMEI2"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>





            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Size"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="سایز"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Color"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="رنگ"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>





            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LMojdegani"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/MacAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="MacAddress"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mojdegani"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="مژدگانی"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LFactor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FactorNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="شماره فاکتور"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/NameForoshande"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="نام فروشنده"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LTarikh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Tarikh_Kharid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="تاریخ خرید"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="نام"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/LastName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="نام خانوادگی"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/CodeMelli"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="کد ملی 10 رقمی"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Mobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="شماره موبایل"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Explain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="توضیحات مربوط به کالا (اختیاری)"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="جنسیت"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

               <RadioGroup
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:weightSum="2">

                   <RadioButton
                       android:id="@+id/mard"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="مرد"/>

                   <RadioButton
                       android:id="@+id/zan"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="زن"/>


               </RadioGroup>


            </LinearLayout>


            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                >

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/confirm"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:text="تایید"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:background="@drawable/confirm"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:clickable="true"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my main xml that have a linearlayout with 4 text that is clickable and by selecting on those texts view pager change between pages .

**Main XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.85">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/card2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="4"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="کالای مسروقه"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/stolled"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="کالای گم شده"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/losted"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="پیدا شده"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/founded"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="کالای نو"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/fresh"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
            >


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: post is editted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `adjustUnspecified` in **Manifest** and its working properly

Answer (score 1):

I think, as per you said in question,you have declared **adjustResize** in your **manifest** like below right?

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Then, please try to adding

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in **parent layout** of your xml.

Comment: not working . i tried adding this to both fragment xml and main xml . but still not working

Comment: Please try to add it - **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** in your scrollview first and if not working then try to add in root linear layout of your code

Comment: I tried it . first i add  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  to scroll view and run the app and still not working after that i added that on the main linearlayout too after running still not working

Answer (score 1):

Add this line inyour **ScrollView** `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

**(or)**

Add this line inside **OncreateView()** `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);)`

```
 serial.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            serial.requestLayout();
            getActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: its not working and also my activity open with an animation

Comment: I used adjustUnspecified and it worked properly . Thanks for your helping